# How can i save the Error thrown by false Login

Tags: java, spring-boot, response

i builded a backend in springboot so far and i am using my api endpoints to test a little bit. My question is how i can get the server response (Json or Http) and save the information in my database?

For example: My login is wrong and i get following json: `{ "timestamp": "2020-09-11T06:37:32.254+00:00", "status": 403, "error": "Forbidden", "message": "", "path": "/api/auth/login" }`

For example: My login is wrong and i get following json:`{"timestamp":"2020-09-11T06:37:32.254+00:00","status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"","path":"/api/auth/login"}`

```
@Column(name = "TIMESTAMP")
private Date timestamp;

@Column(name = "STATUS")
@NotNull
private Long status;

@Column(name = "ERROR")
@NotNull
private String error;

@Column(name = "MESSAGE")
@NotNull
private String message;

@Column(name = "PATH")
private Date PATH;

@Column(name = "U_NAME")
@NotNull
private String username;

public LogEvent(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **@RestControllerAdvice** to manually handle such exceptions.

In handling functions you can generate custom error response and save in db.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class WebRestControllerAdvice {

  @Autowired CustomErrorRepository errorRepository;
  
  @ExceptionHandler(CustomNotFoundException.class)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
  public ResponseMsg handleNotFoundException(Throwable ex) {
    ResponseMsg responseMsg = new ResponseMsg(ex.getMessage());
    errorRepository.save(responseMsg);
    return responseMsg;
  }
}
```

ResponseMsg.class in your case can be LogEvent.class and you can create multiple functions for different exceptions.